# OCSP responder not present?

Tags: openssl, x509, ocsp

Am trying to set up OCSP validation routines, and so want to be comfortable with the environment first.  Found excellent tutorials at for example [OpenSSL: Manually verify a certificate against an OCSP](https://raymii.org/s/articles/OpenSSL_Manually_Verify_a_certificate_against_an_OCSP.html).

Multiple questions arise, so please bear with me.

There have been some changes since that tutorial, but I think the gist is:

1)  snag the certificate you want to verify, e.g.

```
openssl s_client -connect wikipedia.org:443 2>&1 < /dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p' > wikipedia.pem
```

2) build the certificate chain, e.g.

```
openssl s_client -connect wikipedia.org:443 -showcerts 2>&1 < /dev/null > chain.pem
```

and then edit appropriately.  I found that the above doesn't provide the self-signed CA certificate, GlobalSignRootCA, so added that in.

3) Determine the ocsp URI, e.g.

```
openssl x509 -noout -ocsp_uri -in wikipedia.pem
```

which returns

```
http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2
```

4) Invoke the openssl ocsp client, e.g.

```
openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -url http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2
```

which returns

```
[woody@oc2042275410 testCerts]$ openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -url http ://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2
Error querying OCSP responsder
140062843348808:error:27076072:OCSP routines:PARSE_HTTP_LINE1:server response error:ocsp_ht.c:250:Code=403,Reason=Forbidden
```

(responsder?)

I read that this is due to a virtualization issue, so

```
openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -url http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2 -header "HOST" "ocsp2.globalsign.com"
```

which yields

```
Response Verify Failure
140400906352456:error:27069065:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:ocsp_vfy.c:126:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate
wikipedia.pem: good
    This Update: Apr 28 23:10:10 2015 GMT
    Next Update: Apr 29 11:10:10 2015 GMT
```

So I'm getting that the OCSP returned that the cert is good, but this leads to question 1:
***why the error 'unable to get local issuer certificate'?***

Ok, trying again with Google.  Same routine, capturing cert, checking for OCSP URI:

```
openssl x509 -noout -ocsp_uri -in google.pem
```

yields

```
http://clients1.google.com/ocsp.
```

Fair enough:

```
openssl ocsp -issuer gchain.pem -cert google.pem -url http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
Error querying OCSP responsder
140433209165640:error:27076072:OCSP routines:PARSE_HTTP_LINE1:server response error:ocsp_ht.c:250:Code=404,Reason=Not Found
```

Not Found?  That seemed surprising.  Checking with wireshark:

```
> POST /ocsp HTTP/1.0
> Content-Type: application/ocsp-request
> Content-Length: 112

> 0n0l0E0C0A0...+..........j.....p.I.#z...(~d...U.. [.5...J:.......l..9.....{6.#0!0...+.....0......].O.9..}d`.L...
< ~HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 22:42:40 GMT
< Server: sffe
< Content-Length: 1429
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=1
< 
< <!DOCTYPE html>
< <html lang=en>
<   <meta charset=utf-8>
<   <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<   <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
<   <style>
<     *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png) no-repeat}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}
<   </style>
<   <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
<   <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That...s an error.</ins>
<   <p>The requested URL <code>/ocsp</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That...s all we know.</ins>
```

So that is question 2: ***is this correct, the OCSP was moved, and isn't present at the OCSP URI?***  Is it perhaps that the server has uniformly moved to OCSP stapling, and doesn't consider the OCSP server important any longer?

Comment: Did you try adding -noverify to openssl ocsp?

Comment: -noverify works in the first case, although that doesn't explain the error in question 1, just removes it.  I still don't understand why it can't find the local issuer certificate.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding 1)

OCSP has a "Response signing key/certificate pair" used to authenticate the response. This certificate is given in the response to:

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -url http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2 -header "HOST" "ocsp2.globalsign.com" -resp_text
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
UMiqxBNugzQ=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So let's save that to signcert.pem and see what's up:

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer chain_wikipedia.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -url http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2 -header "HOST" "ocsp2.globalsign.com" -resp_text | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p' > signcert.pem
$ openssl verify signcert.pem
signcert.pem: C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign OV CA - SHA256 - G2 OCSP responder - 2, serialNumber = 20150914163800
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Okay... Guess we're missing the intermediate?

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in signcert.pem  | grep -e 'Issuer:' -e '.crt'
Issuer: C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
```

OK, no issuer URI field... That's just dirty.
Let's fetch it from the CA and form a chain:

```
$ curl https://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsorganizationvalsha2g2r1.crt | openssl x509 -inform der -outform pem >> signcert.pem
```

Ok, this should w...:

```
$ openssl ocsp -VAfile signcert.pem -issuer chain_wikipedia.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -url http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2 -header "HOST" "ocsp2.globalsign.com" -resp_text
[...]
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
/TiSgNCpgNg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Response Verify Failure
```

... WTF ?! Oh, different signing cert?!

```
$ cat >> signcert.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID9DCCAtygAwIBAgISESEjxqkycL2lZt0CfS9OgUN2MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
MGYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMRkwFwYDVQQKExBHbG9iYWxTaWduIG52LXNhMTwwOgYD
VQQDEzNHbG9iYWxTaWduIE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiBWYWxpZGF0aW9uIENBIC0gU0hB
MjU2IC0gRzIwHhcNMTUwODIwMTgxOTQxWhcNMTUxMTIwMTgxOTQxWjB9MQswCQYD
VQQGEwJCRTEZMBcGA1UEChMQR2xvYmFsU2lnbiBudi1zYTE6MDgGA1UEAxMxR2xv
YmFsU2lnbiBPViBDQSAtIFNIQTI1NiAtIEcyIE9DU1AgcmVzcG9uZGVyIC0gMTEX
MBUGA1UEBRMOMjAxNTA4MjAyMDE4MDAwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAw
ggEKAoIBAQC+8xxGkIda/04pKK3AXuLz8S8EH4qouLbP/lrd+DFY1oI8fU4kosO+
WjvBPMeK1ZvvR6YjcNhIRsoYsDWdvhMv8/qvu1GQBrs1oC2910lg3fGIR48LR6TR
+XYC1jFv0IHaF5vp+e2nu3diJi7FKHMbP5jVdd1e6cuEcrq+pEW7WkPDQnhzh6U/
GGdhxbH8uk4KPH42Os0Rf6la99EyXzJZ8zccy0ySGnIOF5Km1efXg0qwx3PEk3MQ
fbFG3n4zE7lwBsrEgACI+V9K50tWfJIAm8Ll/xpGhvqF+6swCr0WExMcqaNpdVsf
hiHFD18k8v4R6t7ht+cWx1YvSSA+/hz3AgMBAAGjgYQwgYEwCQYDVR0TBAIwADAO
BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwkwDwYJKwYBBQUHMAEF
BAIFADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU8haQnheoUW3t3+j0OaxZMUgEjIkwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU
lt5h8b0cFilTHMDMfTuDAEDmGnwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAH0MXy5hmHXc
G88ntZ2YcM3C6AAVqpfZ2+KYwL06cjmAFvNx6nWUN2w5MD59fiQC3DENCvlEGe29
d9+zsPM4hwEVRGKBIDueXycI0BNRAViacaks4OqRcc8gi1SBE5j94yt1kfp6VBhc
yQBU4Cg5UBy4OA3SsnYdt/Ur1Xm+BDlpi5WWROM1O5UECquLU3/P1prxF78EkTdv
OSGtP1VLMS47hk5v+sUC3hnfwUyKnr2oiVV6CvxxLOipdeDGl68dVisauNf7Dp9H
YvO8OLkN9es+R2AV5iFIzLWHjsQxLOrY18bi6N0zMP7tuZIRSVpil+b49KJ8T/e1
/TiSgNCpgNg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
^D
```

Fingers crossed...

```
$ openssl ocsp -VAfile signcert.pem -issuer chain_wikipedia.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -url http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2 -header "HOST" "ocsp2.globalsign.com"
Response verify OK
wikipedia.pem: good
        This Update: Sep 15 17:01:20 2015 GMT
        Next Update: Sep 16 05:01:20 2015 GMT
```

Hell yeah!